# Finding mixed Nash equilibrium question

Tags: calculus, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Question

[image]

Are there any NE in which player 1 randomizes (mixes) between all three actions? If yes, characterize all such equilibria. If no, explain why not.

——-

I have solved this question by utilizing this answer: [how to find mixed Nash equilibria for 3x3?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017371/how-to-find-mixed-nash-equilibria-for-3x3)

I found that

For player 1 to be indifferent between T and B

$$4q_L+6q_M+2(1-q_L-q_M)=2+2q_L+4q_M$$

$$6q_L+2q_M+0(1-q_L-q_M)=6q_L+2q_M$$

They should be equal

So I get that $$q_M-2q_L=-1$$

For player 1 to be indifferent between C and B

$$2q_L+8q_M+0(1-q_L-q_M)=2q_L+8q_M$$

So they are equal as well

$$2q_L+8q_M=6q_L+2q_M$$

$$3q_M=2q_L$$

When I combine these two results

$$3q_M=2q_L$$

$$q_M-2q_L=1$$

I obtain $q_M=1/2$ an $q_M=3/4$ But $q_R=-1/4$

So I can say that there is no such a mixed Nash equilibrium.

What I understand that the question ask that player 1 randomizes (mixes) between all three actions.

Did I solve for player 1 or for player 2 in this way? Morespecifically, Could I choose right probability and payoff values from the given table?

Also, my solution is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a sign error in deriving the equilibrium for $T$ and $B$. $2+2q_L+4q_M=6q_L+2q_M$ yields $q_M-2q_L=-1$. If you use that together with $3q_M=2q_L$ you get $q_L,q_M\in[0,1]$ but $q_R=1-q_L-q_M\lt0$, so your conclusion is nevertheless correct.

If you'd found a solution with $q_L,q_M,q_R\in[0,1]$, that would yield a strategy for Player $2$ that would lead Player $1$ to be indifferent among all her options. This is a necessary condition for a Nash equilibrium in which Player $1$ mixes all her strategies (if she weren't indifferent among all of them, she could improve her payoff by changing the mixture), but not yet sufficient. For this to correspond to a Nash equilibrium, Player $2$ must also be indifferent among all options for which the probability is in the interior $(0,1)$ of the interval $[0,1]$. For those options for which the probability is on the boundary $\{0,1\}$, Player $2$ need not be indifferent, but the sign of the derivative must be such that he could only profit by pushing the probability beyond the boundary. Only if there is a strategy for Player $1$ that creates these conditions for Player $2$ do you have a full Nash equilibrium. In particular, in the case $q_L,q_M,q_R\in(0,1)$, where all three probabilities are in the interior, you have to do the same calculation that you did again with roles reversed to show that there is a strategy for Player $1$ that makes Player $2$ indifferent among all three options.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. I corrected my mistake. And your explanation under the presence of solution is very instructive and useful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear @joriki I am studying preliminary exam, if it is possible for you, can you look at my another question? Because your explanation is really helpful. Thanks. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850096/subgame-perfect-equilibrium-question

Comment: @B11b: I'd already seen that question (and improved the formatting), but I don't know enough about economic theory to really help you with that one. Your solution to (i) seems plausible to me, but don't rely on that.

Comment: Okay thank you for your reply. Best Regards..